# Is there a way to pull audio from an user uploaded mp4 and play on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m in a little over my head but I figured I’d ask anyway. I'm building something stupid using  React and trying to take a mp4 file a user uploads, extract the audio from that file, and play that audio every time the user clicks a button on a certain page. I’ve extracted audio from my own mp4 files in the past using ffmpeg and the terminal, but I'm unsure the best way to go about it outside that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to play the audio stream of an mp4 media, then simply use an HTMLAudioElement with its `src` pointing to that media:

```js
document.getElementById( 'inp' )
  .addEventListener( 'change', function( evt ) {
    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    var url = URL.createObjectURL( file );
    var audioElem = new Audio( url );
    audioElem.controls = true;
    document.body.appendChild( audioElem );
  } );
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp" accept="video/*">
```

If you really want to extract the audio stream on its own from this media, you can use the [`WebAudioContext.decodeAudioData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData) method which will extract the raw PCM data from your media:

```js
var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || webkitAudioContext);
document.getElementById( 'inp' )
  .addEventListener( 'change', onfileselect );
  
function onfileselect( evt ) {
  var file = evt.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = handleBuffer;
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer( file );
}
function handleBuffer( evt ) {
  // 'this' === 'reader'
  var buffer_from_file = this.result;
  audioContext.decodeAudioData( buffer_from_file, handleAudioBuffer );
}
function handleAudioBuffer( audioBuf ) {
  // here we have access to an AudioBufferNode, from which we can read the raw PCM data
  var channel0PCM = audioBuf.getChannelData( 0 );
  // we could then reencode this raw PCM to an other compressed format manually
  
  // we can also play this AudioBuffer
  var source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = audioBuf;
  source.connect( audioContext.destination );

  var button = document.createElement( 'button' );
  button.textContent = 'play';
  button.onclick = play;
  document.body.appendChild( button );
  
  function play() {
    source.start( 0 );
    button.textContent = "stop";
    button.onclick = stop;
  }
  function stop() {
    button.remove();
    source.stop( 0 );
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp" accept="video/*">
```

If you wanted to extract the exact stream from the media, without reencoding, then you'd have to use ffmpeg, which has now [a port for js](https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js/).